# What's a good architecture/pattern for developing server-side node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

What's a good architecture/pattern for developing server-side node.js?

I will be using a backbone.js MVC architecture on the front-end, transporting over websockets.

Examples/explanations would be great! Thanks!

Comment: [EDA](https://github.com/Raynos/ExpressArchTest)

Answer (score 3):

MVC on the server-side works great, too. Try [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/). Express has an executable called **express** that should be available if you install from **npm**. When you run **express**, it makes a skeleton file structure of a skeleton app. Here's [a simple](http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/a-simple-mvc-setup-in-node-js) example of an MVC model using Express.

Comment: That's far too vague. Please go into details about why it's great. How it integrates with node.

Comment: I'm using socket.io. Any examples of what good server-side MVC should look like in node?

Comment: @boom, I understand your question better now. I edited my answer that I hope will help you better.